# Javamail and gmail, getting "PKIX path building failed"

Tags: java, eclipse, gmail, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to run a standalone Java class that will connect to Gmail as imap.  Here is the code excerpt (username and pass masked)

```java
    Properties props = System.getProperties();

    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap"); 

    System.out.println("getting session");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

    System.out.println("getting store");

    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");

    System.out.println("connecting");

    store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "xxxxx", "yyyyyy");
```

When trying to run, it displays the "connecting" message but throws this

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I had done the following steps:

- a) (from a Linux instance): openssl s_client -connect
  imap.gmail.com:993
- b) from the above output copied the certificate
  into a pem file, then ran this on Windows

```
keytool -keystore cacerts -import -trustcacerts -alias gmailcert -file c:\gmailcert.pem -storepass changeit
```

The above step was in this folder 
C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk11.0.6_10\lib\security

In Eclipse, where I'm running the class, I set these jvm args

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="c:/Program Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk11.0.6_10/lib/security/cacerts"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="changeit"
```

I also tried

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="c:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk11.0.6_10\lib/security\cacerts"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="changeit"
```

and

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="c:\\Program Files\\Amazon Corretto\\jdk11.0.6_10\\lib\\security\\cacerts"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="changeit"
```

I also referred to this [site](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/how-to-import-a-public-ssl-certificate-into-a-jvm-867025849.html), to make sure I'm importing the gmail cert correctly. I then ran an SSLPoke utility and get the same error, so it's something with the way I'm getting and importing the cert.

What am I missing?

Comment: Ttry importing the cert in `c:/Program Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk11.0.6_10/jre/lib/security/cacerts` and if your app is running on same jre, you need not use `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword`.

Comment: Yep, I did the import into cacerts.  Tried the run with and without the jvm ssl arguments. Same error

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have an anti-virus program that's intercepting the connection.  It would be better if you could configure it to allow a direct connection from your program.  Lacking that, see the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#installcert) for help with the certificate.

Comment: Thanks! I have AVG (paid)  Checked the firewall log and nothing there.  I also checked the FAQ you provided, and tried the props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.trust", "imap.gmail.com"); setting, but that didn't help (I had removed the javax.net.ssl jvm arguments and also removed "props.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true"); ") Still get the same error.

Comment: Resolved:  I went to the blog url mentioned in the JavaMail FAQ, http://s-n-ushakov.blogspot.com/2013/11/yet-another-installcert-for-java-now.html, downloaded the package and ran the script instead of doing the manual openssl and keytool steps.  That took care of the path building ssl failure.  Also, this was the final code for setting properties    Properties props = System.getProperties();
      props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
      props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
      props.setProperty("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true");

Comment: You should not have needed any of those property settings; the defaults should have been good enough.